# Why is Request["url"] set by default?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Even if I don't POST or GET any parameter named url it still get inserted into the Request variable resulting in that `Request["url"]` is always set. The default value is the requested aspx file. If I include url as POST or GET parameter in the request the default value is overwritten. Can you explain why this behavior is implemented in .net?

Comment: Questions on historical reasons are generally not answerable in reasonable way. See Erik Funkenbusch's post for possible reasons. To make your question practical and better fit on SO you may comment on why do you need this information (i.e. "I'm implementing new framewrok/wrapper  classes and interested if I should still support ...."). Note that it is ok to ask [see meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260711/should-why-language-feature-designed-particular-way-be-closed-moved) but actual answer for most of such questions is not expected (especially for decisions made 15+ years ago).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is documented in the HttpRequest class information. Look at the Items collection and it says specifically that it will look at objects from QueryString, Form, Cookies, or ServerVariables. This does go back to classic ASP and other languages have implemented similar, such as PHP although PHP considers it unsafe and I believe it was turned off in v 5.5. Microsoft also recommneded not to do this as it can be exploited. In the case of the Request["url"] it will return a server variable. If a querystring is present with the variable url in it, Request["url"] will return the querystring  variable since it is scanned first in the list. It was put in for backwards compatibility with classic ASP as it was widely used in classic ASP.

[HttpRequest Class MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Why not?  This is the corollary of Eric Lippart's answer to pretty much every "Why doesn't C# implement X" (see [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/06/22/why-doesn-t-c-implement-top-level-methods.aspx))

The reason is "because someone wrote it".  And without the framework designer that wrote it here to say why, we will probably never know.  But, the answer is most likely because "It's a useful shortcut", and likely dates back to the old pre-.net asp classic days.

Comment: I don't know if I agree with the "why not?" catch-all. If you discovered that every time you instantiated a `Dictionary<string, int>` that `dict["teehee"]` resulted in `5` unless overridden, I would sure expect that to be documented somewhere. There should be a documented reason for any unexpected implemented behavior. That being said, Eric Lippert's answer makes sense to me.

Comment: Probably should be comment, not an answer (with possible vote to close)... Also in this case it clearly documented (see my answer), so expected behavior.

Comment: @itsme86 - It is in fact documented as Alexei's answer notes, but that was not what you were asking.. you were asking why it's there in the first place.  And the answer to Why is only known to those that created it, since they did not document the Why.  It's just a shortcut to get server variables, other server variables are also able to be retrieved this way.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov - Actually, yours is the one that should probably be the comment, since you did not actually answer the question asked.. I did.

Comment: I've added comment to the post about the type of question. Consider reordering your post so actual guess/answer is on top so it can be upvoted as best guess so far (and likely the only).

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch a) I didn't ask anything, b) the OP asked why a certain behavior exited, not the developer's intention behind the behavior, c) the "why" asked in the OP's question is clearly answered by Mark Fitzpatrick.

Answer (score 1):

When you use the HttpRequest object with a syntax like **Request["url"]** you are actually doing a search over multiple internal collections by key. The indexer on the HttpRequest is declared as:

```
public string this[string key]{ get; }
```

Indexers are syntactic sugar to be able to access/search any object as an Array, and in fact they are usually used in classes that are some kind of collection.

The HttpRequest class is not an array or a collection, but a much more complex type containing a bunch of different members, including several collections (Cookies, ServerVariables, QueryString, Form etc). The indexer is just an abstraction, to make the Request object accessible like a single collection.

To demonstrate how it works, here is a definition of the indexer very close to the actual .NET 4.5 implementation:

```
public string this[string key]
{
    get
    {
        string val = this.QueryString[key];

        if (val != null)
            return val;

        val = this.Form[key];

        if (val != null)
            return str;

        var cookie = this.Cookies[key];

        if (cookie != null)
            return cookie.Value;

        val = this.ServerVariables[key];

        if (val != null)
            return val;

        return null;
    }
}
```

Now i can finally answer your real question

> If I include url as POST or GET parameter in the request the default value is overwritten. Can you explain why this behavior is implemented in .net?

When you send the "url" parameter by POST or GET you are just adding a value to the Forms or QueryString collections accessed by the indexer, and i don't see anything wrong with that. All the internal HttpRequest collections (Cookies, QueryStrings etc.) can be modified in any part of your code anyway.

> Where does the default Request["url"] value come from?

The ServerVariables collection.

> Is it dangerous to POST or GET the url parameter?

Yes if you are using **Request["url"]** in C# and don't know how it works. It should definitely not be used to access the current path. You should use the Request.Path property instead.